# Retrieve Spark DF schema as generated when declared

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a spark df which on declaration generated the schema info as

```
val a = df
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [an_array: array<int>, a_map: map<string,string>, a_struct: struct<x:int>, an_array_of_structs: array<struct<foo:string,bar:int,vals:array<double>>>]
```

while on doing `df.schema` I get

```
res11: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(an_array,ArrayType(IntegerType,false),true), StructField(a_map,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true), StructField(a_struct,StructType(StructField(x,IntegerType,false)),true), StructField(an_array_of_structs,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(foo,StringType,true), StructField(bar,IntegerType,false), StructField(vals,ArrayType(DoubleType,false),true)),true),true))
```

How do I retrieve the previous info in a variable rather than the complex schema info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a `simpleString`:

```
df.schema.simpleString
```